# Searching for a blank field in a web view?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a search in a webview
?SearchView&SearchOrder=4&Query=%5BPrice%5D%3E%3D0+AND+%5BPrice%5D%3C%3D999999999999999

How can I search for Price when it is blank?

I tried
?SearchView&SearchOrder=4&Query=Price%5D%3D%47%47

but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is the same as for the search in the client. See [this link](http://www.alanlepofsky.net/alepofsky/alanblog.nsf/dx/searching-for-blank-fields?opendocument&comments) to find out more. 
The sxyntax is:

```
not [FieldName] is present
```

Your example would then be:

```
?SearchView&SearchOrder=4&Query=not%20[Price]%20is%20present
```

Comment: I get Query is not understandable.   And I think because the field is numeric (and most values are) but a few fields are blank ("").   If I search on another  text only field then it works fine.

Comment: hmm... then I am sorry... You might test for [FieldName] > 0

Comment: Given what you've said here, I'd strongly suggest running an agent and fixing it so that the Price field is always either the correct type or omitted completely.  Leaving those empty text values in there is an invitation to more problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that while searching for such an answer, I found in release 6.5 (web view search) that this : "not [FieldName] is present" - didn't work. It gives "Query is not understandable".

I also tried it in Notes 8.5 (client). This just gave no results (ie also didn't work)

I didn't find an answer exept to set a computed field "xxxIsBlank" to "Yes" when my search field is blank.

Now I can FT search for [xxxIsBlank] = "Yes". Clunky... didn't like it as a solution but it has worked.